# How can I call a share compare function for array.sort in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to call a shared comparer function from an array.sort to sort 2 different arrays.

if i have:

```
projects.sort(
        function(a, b){
          var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
          var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
          if (x < y) {return -1;}
          if (x > y) {return 1;}
          return 0;
        });
```

and

```
products.sort(
        function(a, b){
          var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
          var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
          if (x < y) {return -1;}
          if (x > y) {return 1;}
          return 0;
        });
```

how can i do this?

```
projects.sort(sortArray());
products.sort(sortArray());
```

Comment: Don't put the parentheses after `sortArray`: `projects.sort(sortArray)`

Answer (score 3):

Create a named function:

```
function compare(a, b){
  var x = a.name.toLowerCase();
  var y = b.name.toLowerCase();
  if (x < y) {return -1;}
  if (x > y) {return 1;}
  return 0;
}
```

Then you can reference this function when you call `sort`:

```
projects.sort(compare);
products.sort(compare);
```

Comment: thank you, Peter!  for some reason when i tried this it didn't work.  It's working now, beautifully.  much appreciated for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortItems(a,b) {
  var   x = a.name.toLowerCase(),
        y = b.name.toLowerCase()

  return x.localeCompare(y);
 }

// Then use this
projects.sort(sortItems);
products.sort(sortItems);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer, it will help users with their future searches.